# Android SMS multi text groups

Tags: android, sms

My project is a checklist of phone numbers in a `recyclerView`/`cardView`. The phone numbers/businesses can be added or subtracted by a checkBox to make individual groups. I want to be able to send a group multi-text to the selected individuals.

My problem is that only the first phone number (recipient) in a group receives the message while the rest receive nothing, but the numbers still display in the edit text (the first is the only functioning number).

I have tried a lot of different ways but nothing has worked, I am about to give up.

No one seems to know how to fix this problem. If this problem can be solved please let me know.

I don't want to loop the numbers and text individually, that was a suggested fix.

This is the phone activity:

```
public class ACPhone extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String SEPARATOR = ";";
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;
    TextView txtView;
    Button btnsend;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_acphone);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMessageMass);
        btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null){

            ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedNumbers = 
            intent.getCharSequenceArrayListExtra(SELECTED_NUMBERS);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedNumbers.size(); i++) {
                sb.append(selectedNumbers.get(i));
                if (i != selectedNumbers.size() - 1){
                    sb.append(SEPARATOR);
            }
        }
        txtPhoneNo.setText(sb.toString());
    }
    btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override public void onClick(View v) {

            String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
            String messageView = txtView.getText().toString();

            if (phoneNo.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0) {
                sendMessage(phoneNo, message, messageView);
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please enter message", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    }

    private void sendMessage(String phoneNo,String message, String staticMessage){

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo,null,message + "\n" + 
   staticMessage,null,null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to send. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of all the numbers and do a for loop through the list in your onclick or in a method and call it in onclick. That's how I would do it anyway.

Comment: You mean send individual messages to each checked recipient rather than a one message to a group of selected recipients?

Comment: Yes. Keep the message the same and just loop through the numbers.

Comment: that was suggested by the codementor after the app it didn't work. I really didn't want to text each person individually. I thought it could be done as a mass text.  I will try another mentor if I cant find someone on stack.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the some steps to send one single message to multiple contact when it is checked.

**Step 1 :** In your `MainActivity.class` like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
EditText editMessage;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Handler progresshandler;
boolean isThreadRunning;
int i;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactsView);
    editMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessage);

    listView.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(this, contacts));

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Sending Messages.. Please wait!");

    progresshandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Messages Sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
  }

}
```

**Step 2 :** Create one class within this `MainActivity.class`(Put this class below `onCreate()` method)

```
class SendMessagesThread extends Thread {
    Handler handler;

    public SendMessagesThread(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void run() {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        // Find out which contacts are selected
        for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
            View item = (View) listView.getChildAt(i);
            boolean selected = ((CheckBox) item.findViewById(R.id.selected)).isChecked();
            if (selected) {
                String mobile = ((TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();
                try {
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(mobile, null, editMessage.getText().toString(), null, null);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.d("Mobile", "Could not send message to " + mobile);
                }
            }
        }
        Message m = handler.obtainMessage();
        handler.sendMessage(m);
    } // run
} // Thread
```

**Step 3:** Create one method(put this method below step - 2)

```
public void sendMessages(View v) {
    if (editMessage.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
        SendMessagesThread thread = new SendMessagesThread(progresshandler);
        thread.start();
        progressDialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

**Note :** According to my project, I am not using any SQLite database or webservice.Basically, I am fetching all the contact from device contact book and displaying that contact to listview. So, Try to understand and modify.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  That would work, but I would still have to load new contacts into the users contact list. I could do that problematically.  I decided to go with the ugliest solution.  It isn't pretty, but it works, ( I think).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedNumbers 
 =getIntent().getCharSequenceArrayListExtra(SELECTED_NUMBERS);;

    String phNumbers = "";
    for (CharSequence s: selectedNumbers) {
        phNumbers += s + ";";
    }

 //      for (int i = 0; i < selectedNumbers.size(); i++) {
//            phNumbers += selectedNumbers.get(i);
//          if (i != selectedNumbers.size()-1){
//               phNumbers += ";";
//            }
//        }

    phNumbers = phNumbers.substring(0, phNumbers.length() - 1);
    String message = "";
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", phNumbers);
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",message);
    startActivity(smsIntent);

}
}
```